# get value id record from checkbox and loop to get that's record

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and write code for cruds some table, but im intend import the data that checked by users to pdf files.
im using loop like this to show data

```
$i=0 + $offset;
        foreach ($cards as $c) {
            $this->table->add_row( '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$i.'" value="'.$c->NoKartu.'" onchange="cek()">', 
                ++$i, $c->UserID, $c->NoKartu,
                $c->FlagMain, $c->FlagAktiv, $c->TransDate, $c->MerchantID,
                '<a href="'.$this->config->item('base_url').'index.php/cards/updateCard/'.$c->NoKartu.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
                anchor('cards/delete/'.$c->NoKartu, '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">', array('onclick' => "return confirm('Apakah Anda Yakin Ingin Menghapus Data Kartu Ini ?')"))
                );
        }
```

and pdf import function like this

```
function download_pdf(){
        $this->load->library('cezpdf');
        $db_data = array();
        //$db_data = $this->mKartu->get_all_data()->result_array();
        $jumlah = $this->mKartu->count_all();
        for($i=0;$i<$jumlah;$i++){
            $id = $this->input->get($i);
            $db_data = $this->mKartu->get_by_id($id)->result_array();
        }

        $col_names = array();
        $this->cezpdf->ezTable($db_data);
        $this->cezpdf->ezStream();
    }
```

can someone tell my fault ? very thank's before

Comment: where is your javascript cek() function

Comment: function cek(){
                var tbl = document.getElementById("lineItemTable");
                var rowLen = tbl.rows.length;
                var jumlah = 0;
                for (var idx = 1; idx < rowLen; idx++) {
                  var row = tbl.rows[idx];
                  var cell = row.cells[0];
                  var node = cell.lastChild;
                  if (node.checked == true)
                    jumlah++;

                  document.getElementById('jumlah').value = jumlah;
                }
              }

Comment: actually i've resolved this problem, thank's for you're comments